# bpel.xml not found for quartz schedule(11g does not have this file), how we associate Quartz property in composite.xml

Tags: java, soa, oracle11g, bpel

I have created a BPEL process in which a dataadapter polling for a table.
I want to schedule this process by quartz scheduler using following parameters

```
> <activationAgents> 
>      <activationAgent className="oracle.tip.adapter.fw.agent.jca.JCAActivationAgent"
> 
>                          partnerLink="readFileService"
> heartBeatInterval="10"> 
>            <property name="schedulerCallout">DefaultSchedulerCalloutImpl</property>
> 
>            <property name="endpointScheduleOn">0 0 19 * *
> ?</property> 
>            <property name="endpointScheduleOff">0 30 19 * *
> ?</property> 
>     </activationAgent  </activationAgents>
```

after seeing many forums i found this, but they are updating these values in bpel.xml.  and I am not able to find it in my application.

I am using Jdeveloper 11.3 and oracle 11g SOA.. please help me

**After doing some googling I found in version 10g we are able to fing BPEL.xml and in 11g we have composite.xml. but now the issue is how i can add these Quartz configurables in composite.xml file(as its showing me error while adding this)**

Comment: After doing some googling I found in version 10g we are able to fing BPEL.xml and in 11g we have composite.xml.